# teradata query for updating the column size

Tags: teradata

I have a table name "Currency" and it has a column name "cur" of type DECIMAL(12,6). I want to increase this size to DECIMAL(12,8). Please suggest me the query for this in Teradata. I don't want to loose previous datas.

Comment: alter table <tablename> add <columnname> DECIMAL(12,8)

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya this is not working . is there any other way? thanks

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya this construction works only for type varchar. https://docs.teradata.com/r/WurHmDcDf31smikPbo9Mcw/Xix1PWCb0CK~mCtI6hI9DA

Answer (score 0):

Changing the precision of a DECIMAL is not allowed (you could if this was a `NUMBER`instead).

The best way is probably:

- create a new table with the correct datatype
- MERGE the old into the new
- DROP the old and RENAME new to old

Of course you should also increase the scale to DECIMAL(14,8), otherwise you might get an *numeric overflow* error

Comment: I have created an new table with updated column size. Now how to merge it? please tell a simple query without any condions cause I want all the datas to be merged in the new table without any data loss. Thanks

Comment: please suggest I searched a lot and tried so many things but I am unable to copy datas from one table to another

Comment: @SanjeetSingh: You can simply insert/select, but using `MERGE`  (http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_151K/ch03.023.159.html) is more efficient, see: http://developer.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2013/08/why-dont-you-use-alter-table-to-alter-a-table

Comment: @dnoeth - Link to you blog entry is now broken.  Shame, I would love to read this!  Please post revised link if it's still available somewhere.

Comment: @dsz Here you are :-) https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_blog&sys_id=c698df271b9bfb00682ca8233a4bcb9f

Answer (score 0):

Update: Thanks to @denoeth for the hint about simply renaming the `temp` column.  Much better than needing a *double* copy.

Or via a temp column:

```
ALTER TABLE My.Table ADD temp varchar(100);
UPDATE      My.Table SET temp = my_column;
ALTER TABLE My.Table DROP my_column;
ALTER TABLE My.Table RENAME temp TO my_column;
```

This will change the column layout of the table (putting `my_column` to the "back" of the table).

If you work in an environemnt where column ordering is hard-coded anywhere, this could be fatal!

Comment: Simply renaming temp to my_column avoids steps 4 to 6. And increasing the size of a VarChar is allowed in ALtER TABLE :-)